# In modern application design, how do you implement / between TransferOject and BusinessObject

Tags: java, architecture, facade, application-design

With organizations which are slow to adapt to modern technology finally junking EJBs and getting ready to transform to SpringBoot, Microservices, REST, Angular, there are some some questions application design. One being about TransferObjects and Business Objects

1. When the call comes to the REST Controller, is it still popular to populate a TO (POJO) and then make Service call, which in turn populates a BusinessObject and then calls a Repository service?

***OR***

2. At the REST Controller layer do we directly populate the BO and send it to the Service (This does not make any sense to me, because a BO is populated only during the execution business logic).

If nowadays its still Option 1, then how do we avoid writing to exactly similar POJO classes in most cases (in order to use BeanUtils.copyProperties()), with the BO decorated with @Id, @Column etc.

Comment: "*When the call comes to the REST Controller, is it still popular to populate a TO (POJO) and then make Service call, which in turn populates a BusinessObject and then calls a Repository service?*" - Yes. The input channel (e.g. HTTP) is of no concern to the business layer. The business layer expects some request as input, does operations (possibly loading/creating/modifying business objects) and returns some response as output. The business object should not cross the service boundary.

Comment: While we are on the topic: same reasoning goes for the persistence layer. Do not pass business objects 1:1 to the pesistence layer. Rather, pass requests and expect responses. Map between them and the business entities.

Comment: If you don't want to write exactly similar properties for BeanUtils, take a look at other libraries such as `MapStruct`. It gives you great freedom in how you wish to map properties.

Comment: @Turing85 "_italic_ While we are on the topic: same reasoning goes for the persistence layer. Do not pass business objects 1:1 to the pesistence layer. Rather, pass requests and expect responses. Map between them and the business entities._italic_ " - sorry you lost me there. So with this design we have CustomerTO, CustomerBO and CustomerEntity? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Nothing more to elaborate. You pretty much summed it up. If you need some buzzwords, search for hexagonal architecture, onion architecture, clean architecture or ports and adapters.

Comment: @Turing85 arent we duplicating a lot of code for that. It easily shows up in the CopyPasteDetector.

Comment: Counter-question: What is more important? [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) or [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)? You be the judge. The answer is inherently opinion-based.

Comment: @Turing85 would this be a viable design? CustomerBase (containing only the private fields), CustomerTO extends CustomerBase (contains the g/s); CustomerBO extends CustomerBase (another set of g/s), CustomerEntity will be separate ofcourse. Then again, if custMailing1 changes to custStreet1, then it has to be done in all the POJOs. With the above approach, you avoid that somewhat. Yes I agree, its a fine line between DRY or Sep of Concerns. It drives me mad these days.

Comment: @Jaims I will have to study this. Thank you for introducing me to it.

Comment: @Turing85 - you should be putting your comments into an answer, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on @Turing85's comments...

Option 1 usually (see the end of my answer) makes infinitely more sense.  It's a question of responsibility (purpose) and change; the two logical components you refer to, a REST API and a repository / system service:

- **Responsibility**: a REST service cares about working with its callers, so ideally when designing a REST API you should be involving someone from the client-side (client as in caller), because if the API doesn't work for them it's not going to be an effective API.  On the other hand, repositories are somewhat self-centered, and may need to consider things that are or no interest to API callers (and vis-versa).
- **Change**: if you pay attention to design principles, like SOLID, you'll know that part of a system should do one job - as a way of limiting the reasons why it needs to change (see: [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)).  Trying to use one object across both outward-facing API's, and inward-facing repositories, is asking for trouble because it's trying to do too much - its trying to help solve problems in two very different parts of the wider solution, and thee both have very different change drivers working against them.  Turning85's comment about the persistence layer stems from the same idea.

**"Option 1 usually makes infinitely more sense":**

One case where the REST API's objects will / can bear a very close resemblance to those that hit the actual repository (or even be reused, I guess) is when the REST API is a **System API** - i.e. a dedicated façade / proxy to the repository.  In this case, the System API is largely driven by the repository i.e. the main change driver is just the repository.

Comment: The "Sytem API" makes sense. I work in an industry, where 90% of the Use Cases are just that. But lets take an example of a REST call to updateCustPhone(CustomerTO cust) {}..  it calls the Service and then the Repo which populates the CustomerEntity and then persists it. Now this is not a system API (is it?). So yes I agree we should have 2 TOs.. but is there anyway to to reduce the code. In this particular case CustomerTO and CustomerEntity will have the same fields. Change in one necessitates, change in the other.  (Please refer to my comment on CustomerBase)

Comment: RE CustomerBase - I guess it could work, although alternatively you could just use the TO as the base that BO inherits off.  I'm not sure what the difference is / value to be gained is, by using a base class *and* a TO class, when a simple TO should be sufficient.

Comment: Just be aware that the more code you reuse, the more tightly-coupled things can become - depending on how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

After researching a bit I agree, keeping things simple will result in simpler code. I found a nice simple way to take care of this manual work.

https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application